# remove sequential numbers from int array / int list

Tags: c#, .net

im generating a list of numbers such as 100 101 102 103 110 111 112 130 131 132  and i want to remove numbers that are sequential till the next number but with a specific tolerance...

so with a tolerance of 3 for example my output will be
100 102
110 112
130 132

the tolerance value must be adjustable...

ADRS is my list of int's,
ADRSC is my list of strings after being cleaned

```
for (int v = 0; v <= ADRS.Count - 2; v++)
{
    if (v == 0) //adds first number
        ADRSC.Add(ADRS[v].ToString());

    if (ADRS[v]-(int.Parse(ADRSC.Last())) > 3) 
    {
        ADRSC.Add(ADRS[v].ToString());
    }
}
```

*in short:*
i want to remove the numbers inbetween, that have a difference of under 3

**This worked**

```
 adrCache = Nums.First();
        for (int x=1; x < Nums.Count-2; x++)
        {
            if ((Nums[x+1] - adrCache) <= 4)
            {
                adrCache = Nums[x+1];
                Nums[x] = 0; //ill then just remove all zeros
            }
            else {
                adrCache = Nums[x];
            }

        }
```

Comment: if you want to remove number from list you need to iterate it in reverse, or copy the item in new list and then iterate the new list and remove the item from first list, if you remove the item from from list in normal way you will receive index out of range exception

Comment: tolerance of 3 means one in between? As 102 - 100 is 2, so I assume you mean the number of elements within an **inclusve** range of 3, don´t you?

Comment: are there allways 3 (or as much as tolerance) subsequent elements in your input-list? Or would 100, 101, 102, 103 with tolerance of 3 also be valid?

Comment: Please only use IDE tags for questions about the IDE itself, not for general programming questions. And please be sure to read the usage guidance before using a tag.

Comment: Your statement and the example are a little hard to understand. You state that you want to ***"remove numbers that are sequential"***, but then in a series of `100, 101, 102, 103` you remove `101` and `103`. Those numbers aren't sequential.

Comment: basically i want to remove the numbers inbetween, that have a difference of under 3

Comment: If i have 100 101 102 103 110 120 , i want to output 101 103 100 110 120

Comment: Can you list some other examples? LIke what would be the output from an input of `{1,2,3,4,5}` with a tolerance of `3`? Or an input of `{1,2,3,4,6,7,8,10,11}` with a tolerance of `2`? Try to add details that clarify the specific question, and remove details that distract from it (like a "cleaned" list of strings)

Comment: Could you explain the `tolerance of 3` in detail? It's hard to understand the relationship between it and list.

Comment: adrCache = Nums.First();
            for (int x=1; x < Nums.Count-2; x++)
            {
                if ((Nums[x+1] - adrCache) <= 4)
                {
                    adrCache = Nums[x+1];
                    Nums[x] = 0;
                }
                else {
                    adrCache = Nums[x];
                }
                    
            } this was my solution

Answer (score 2):

Here's a shot at what you're looking for, but the question is a little unclear to me:

```
public static List<int> RemoveSequential(List<int> items, int tolerance)
{
    if (items == null || items.Count < 2) return items;
    var result = new List<int> {items.First()};
    var sequenceCount = 0;

    for(int i = 1; i < items.Count; i++)
    {
        if (Math.Abs(items[i] - items[i - 1]) == 1)
        {
            sequenceCount++;
            if (sequenceCount == tolerance - 1)
            {
                result.Add(items[i]);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            sequenceCount = 0;
            result.Add(items[i]);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Usage would look like:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var input = new List<int> {100, 101, 102, 103, 110, 111, 112, 130, 131, 132};
    var output = RemoveSequential(input, 3);

    Console.WriteLine($"Input:  {string.Join(", ", input)}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Output: {string.Join(", ", output)}");

    GetKeyFromUser("\nDone! Press any key to exit...");
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: currently it outputs 1714218
1714219
1714220
1714221
1714222
1714223
1714224
1714227
1714229
1714246
1714247
1714248
1714249
1714250
1714251
1714252
1714255
1714257
1714260
1714261
1714262
1714263
1714264
1714265
1714266
1714269
1714271, i want it too display 1714218, 1714229, 1714246 ,1714271 , only 2 values, nothing inbetween unless greater than 3

Comment: Thank you for your reply. the output as per your example should be 100 103 110 112 130 132 :) tia

Comment: In the question you said, *"so with a tolerance of 3 for example my output will be 100 102 110 112 130 132"*. In the new output in your comment, what rule says that it should output `132`, when that number is consecutive but less than `3` from `130`? The code can be modified to not subtract one from `tolerance` if you're changing what it means. Please be specific about the rules, and provide (in your original question) additional sample inputs and expected outputs that give example of the rule. Also, I have no idea what you're saying in the first comment above.